# Error installing Sql Server sink - Semantic logging

Tags: semantics

I'm trying to install Semantic logging Sql Server sink into my application but each attempt so far failed. The error I'm getting is (in CMD mode):

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging (≥ 1.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 4.5)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.Data (≥ 6.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling (≥ 6.0)'.
Installing 'EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling 6.0.1304.0'.
You are downloading EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://www.opensource.org/licenses/ms-pl. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Install failed. Rolling back...
install-package : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], PathTooLongException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Tried both UI and command prompt installations still no luck. Any help would be appreciated very much.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. You might try to move just this single package to a shorter directory, e.g. C:\Packages. Otherwise move your whole project path (e.g. C:\users\yourname\documents...) to a short path like c:\MyProjects.